# Android studio app works, but sometimes gives an error on other devices

Tags: java, android-studio

I've tried on an asus zenfone 5 and the app worked, but when I run  it on xiaomi, the app crashes and forces to close.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the crash?
Also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have a look at [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) for some troubleshooting instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that no one will help you without error report. As for me I had the same problem and I started using crashlytics which was made by Fabric.io. This service will help you with all your errors when it will send you the notification and error report with too comfort representation. I think that [this](https://get.fabric.io/) link will help you. Good luck :)

P.S. Please share some error report with us so we will help you.

Comment: There's no error in my android studio. But force close when i run the app. In 1 device actually work. But in another device force close

Comment: every crash has stacktrace, please share it with us and we will help you :)